# How to move/rotate objects around another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[[image: ![Picture of the conveyor Belt[1]]

Hello everyone! 
I had a plan to make all of these cubes rotate around in a conveyor belt fashion.

My first thought was to animate each one to rotate around. I haven't done that option because I feel like that would overall cause issues.

My second thought was to make a bunch of empty lerp points, have the objects lerp around and have a trigger on the end set their rotation to about the right angle of the black conveyor belt center.

These will most likely both work, but may take more effort than is necessary.

Is there a better way to do this? Does Unity have a feature that I am unaware of?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One way to approach is would be to almost physically model it: Give the inner transporting shape around which the others rotate an appropriate mesh, then have each chain of the conveyor belt always move forward, but at every step raycast relative-down towards the inner transporting mesh and snap-align the chain part onto the surface hit. (Ensuring each forward movement step is multiplied via Time.deltaTime to have all be in sync.) As perhaps more common alternative to all that, consider [following a bezier curve](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/).